# Fake unresolved import error in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

PyDev is reporting import errors which don't exist. The initial symptom was a fake "unresolved import" error, which was fixed by some combination of:

- Cleaning the Project
- Re-indexing the project (remove interpreter, add again)
- Restarting Eclipse
- Burning incense to the Python deities

Now the error is "unverified variable from import"--it can't seem to find pymssql.connect.

This IS NOT a PYHTONPATH problem. I can access the module just fine, the code in the file with the (alleged) error runs fine---it has unit tests and production code calling it.

The error is somewhere in PyDev: I added a new module to my PyDev project, and the error only occurs in the new module. I've tried all of the above.

---

So, I was planning on posting this code somewhere else to solicit some comments about the design, and I was asked in the comments to post code. (Inspired by: [Database connection wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367857/database-connection-wrapper) and Clint Miller's answer to this question: [How do I correctly clean up a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object)). The import error happens at line 69 (self.connection = pymssql.connect...). Not sure what good this does in answering the question, but...

```
import pymssql
from util.require_type import require_type

class Connections(object):
    @require_type('host', str)
    @require_type('user', str)
    @require_type('password', str)
    @require_type('database', str)
    @require_type('as_dict', bool)
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database, as_dict=True):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db = database
        self.as_dict = as_dict

    @staticmethod
    def server1(db):
        return Connections('','','','')

    @staticmethod
    def server2(db):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def server3(db):
        pass


class DBConnectionSource(object):
    # Usage:
    #        with DBConnectionSource(ConnectionParameters.server1(db = 'MyDB)) as dbConn:
    #            results = dbConn.execute(sqlStatement)

    @require_type('connection_parameters', Connections)
    def __init__(self, connection_parameters=Connections.server1('MyDB')):
        self.host = connection_parameters.host
        self.user = connection_parameters.user
        self.password = connection_parameters.password
        self.db = connection_parameters.db
        self.as_dict = connection_parameters.as_dict
        self.connection = None

    def __enter__(self):

        parent = self

        class DBConnection(object):
            def connect(self):
                self.connection = pymssql.connect(host=parent.host,
                                                  user=parent.user,
                                                  password=parent.password,
                                                  database=parent.db,
                                                  as_dict=parent.as_dict)

            def execute(self, sqlString, arguments={}):
                if self.connection is None:
                    raise Exception('DB Connection not defined')
                crsr = self.connection.cursor()
                crsr.execute(sqlString, arguments)
                return list(crsr)

            def cleanup(self):
                if self.connection:
                    self.connection.close()

        self.connection = DBConnection()
        self.connection.connect()
        return self.connection

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        self.connection.cleanup()
```

Comment: I'm happy to, I just don't know what I'd post, other than an import statement (import pymssql) and a call to a function (pymssql.connect). I'm fairly certain this is a PyDev environment issue, as I can run the code that I;ve written just fine.

Comment: I suppose the first few lines that show the import statements, and let us know which version of the eggs you are importing + the Python version + PyDev version + Eclipse Version

Comment: `>>> import pymssql
>>> pymssql.__version__
'2.0.0'`

Comment: Also: Python 2.7.3, Eclipse 4.2, PyDev 2.7.1. Sorry---I thought I had put these in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ctrl+1` at the line where the error and add a comment saying that you are expecting that import.  This should resolve the PyDev error, as it does static code analysis and not runtime analysis.

Comment: So, I'm using a Mac. I tried Command-1, and it gave me a list of options: 'Create method', 'Create class', and '@UndefinedMethod'. Clicking on the last option doesn't do anything.

Comment: @BenDundee did you go to the line where the issue was?  There should be an option that says something along the lines of ignore error or add a comment

Comment: @BenDundee I will check this after work on my home environment.

Comment: @BenDundee Oh I see where you are at, go to the import line and show me that screenshot

Comment: It finds the module, it just doesn't seem to be indexing it properly.

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR version: read the fifth grey box.***

Your problem (and mine) appears to be due to multiple levels of imports that should be, but is not, handled correctly. Somewhere along the line, linkage is lost.

Assume for a moment that you have a file

```
foo/bar.py
```

and that within that file, you have a symbol named

```
wazoo=15
```

If you then try:

```
from foo import bar
from bar import wazoo <-- false error here
```

Or if you try to use:

```
from foo import bar
...
i = bar.wazoo <-- false error here
```

You ***may*** get the false unresolved error on ***wazoo***. Being a bug, this is obviously inconsistent.

If however, you do the following:

```
from foo.bar import wazoo
```

The problems do seem to go away.

As an aside, I've noted that this sometime seems to happen for newly-defined symbols within an imported file.
Furthermore, the earlier false errors for some symbols within that file will magically disappear, with the only the new error remaining. This implies that there might be some sort of state file that isn't being cleaned, EVEN WHEN you "buildall", etc.

Note also that this problem seems to occur the most for me when I use the Python enum hack...perhaps this will provide a clue to the PyDev-elopers (is PyDev even being maintained anymore?):

bar.py:

```
def enum(**enums):
  return type('Enum', (), enums)

SOMETHING = enum(A=1, B=2)
```

someotherfile.py:

```
from foo import bar
from bar import SOMETHING
...
x = SOMETHING.A
```

Answer (score 0):

I added # @UndefinedVariable to the end of the line throwing the error.

This isn't much of a permanent fix, but at least it got rid of the red from my screen for the time being.  If there is a better long term fix, I would be happy to hear it.